# Touch feedback during swipe left and right

Tags: ionic-framework, swipe, gesture, swipe-gesture

My app has a master-detail structure, where the user can tap on a master item to go to the detail view and then swipe left or right to navigate to other details items.

I'm using on-swipe-left and on-swipe-right to let users swipe between the detail views, however, when the user swipes, there is no visual feedback that there is a swipe happening. Only after the user has fully swiped does anything happen. I thought I could use the slide box, because the slidebox does provide visual feedback as soon as you start swiping, however, my views have vertical scroll and that conflicts with the left and right swipe actions due to the swipe sensitivity. In other words, when the user touches the screen to begin scrolling down, the swipe action takes over and it tries to swipe left or right instead of scrolling down.

So, what are my options? Is there any way I can provide some kind of an animation with on-swipe-left and on-swipe-right so that there is some kind of visual feedback (may be an ink trail on the screen) I can show the user? Or is there any way I can make the slidebox approach work so that the horizontal swipe and vertical scroll can function harmoniously? I have seen other apps that have scroll and swipe functions working harmoniously--gmail and pinterest are examples. Just not able to get it working with ionic.

Or is there another UI pattern that I am not thinking of? Worst case, I could provide buttons for next and previous, but this is a mobile app, so I really shouldn't have to resort to that.

Thanks!